# recursive search in cmake post build

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I want all the files with a particular extension in CMake in a directory. These extension files are generated post running the build.
I tried

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE GCOV_OBJECTS $ENV{OUTPUT_UT_DIR} *Test.cpp.o)
```

But this is getting executed before running the build. I want something like this

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                  COMMAND my_command_to_get_all_desired_files
```

Using file command inside `add_custom_command` is giving me a syntax error. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: `my_command_to_get_all_desired_files` "get" where? where do you want to "get" them? You want to _print_ them? Is this XY question? `Using file command` "file command inside add_custom_command"?

Comment: Get files mean, I need all those files in a list. I need to execute a command on those files. like `gcov ${GCOV_OBJECTS}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cmake script:

```
# mycmakescript.cmake
file(GLOB_RECURSE GCOV_OBJECTS $ENV{OUTPUT_UT_DIR} *Test.cpp.o)
message("${GCOV_OBJECTS}")
#  I need to execute a command on those files. like gcov ${GCOV_OBJECTS}
execute_process(COMMAND gvoc ${GCOV_OBJECTS})
```

and call it when building:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
              COMMAND cmake -P mycmakescript.cmake)
```

Comment: can I make a function in .cmake file and call it to return this `${GCOV_OBJECTS}`?

Comment: You seem to want to move back in time and set a variable? The order of events is: configure stage then build stage. You can't go back in time from build stage to set a variable at configure stage. `I need to execute a command on those files` Then you _do not need a variable_. Just execute the command, from inside `mycmakescript.cmake`.